# How to fix "1 value required as left operand of assignment"?

Tags: c, timer, counter

I want to build a project, where a counter counts up, every time a measurement is under 800 and resets if a measurement is over 800. I tried lots of things, but many didn't work, and some were way to complicated. Please help me... This down there is my original code, which doesn't work.

```
const int sensor = A0;
int x;

void setup(){
x = 0;
}

void loop(){
int Val = analogRead(sensor);
if(Val =< 800){
x + 1;
}
else{
x = 0;
}
delay(250);
}
```

Comment: The [relational operators (C11 6.5.8)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8) are `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` ... you're using `=<` which is an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your if condition, you are not setting the value of variable. You are just giving an  expression.

```
if(Val =< 800){
x + 1;
}
```

The correct code would be assigning the new value to the variable again, and also your relational operator is wrong.. it should be `<=`

```
if(Val <= 800){
x = x + 1;
}
```